# Flexslider slow Image loading issue with webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, flexslider

i have noticed a small glitch on with my [click here for plugin](https://github.com/woothemes/flexslider) slides-show in both safari and chrome [click here](http://janvierlondon.com/index.php)when you first load the page only the top half of the image is visible, Then comes into place once you adjust your browser size. I have noticed the issue started to occur when i add the parameter `smoothHeight: true,` to the `(function()`Javascript. Below is also a css snippet of my css for the slider.

```
.homeslider{
width: 97.5%;
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
   }

.flex-control-nav, .flex-control-paging{
  display: none;
   }

.slides, .flex-control-nav, .flex-direction-nav {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
list-style: none;
   } 

 .flexslider .slides > li {
display: none; 
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
top: 0;
   } 

   .no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}

 .slides:after {
content: "."; 
display: block; 
clear: both; 
visibility: hidden; 
line-height: 0; 
height: 0;
   } 

   html[xmlns] .slides {
display: block;
      } 

    * html .slides {height: 1%;}
```

Any ideas on what maybe causing the issue ?

Comment: Try loading the flexslider.js file before your main.js file. As an aside you have two closing FORM tags on that page after your #newsletter-form

Comment: Thanks, I have made those changes, i havent really noticed a difference.

Comment: Do you see the same issue on the demo page? http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ If not then try and see what is different on your set up as compared to that page.